# Unable to get Day from date in Power Bi in direct query mode

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using direct query mode in power Bi, and I unable to use format function or add column from query editor. I want Day like this table:

| Full Date | Day |
| --- | --- |
| 21/10/2022 | 21 |
| 1/5/2022 | 1 |

Is there any other way I could get Day from date in direct query mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can extract day from date. You can use DAX

```
Day = day(Data[Full Date])
```

OR

```
Day = VALUE(FORMAT(Data[Full Date],"dd"))
```

[image]

You can also do it at query editor by going to add Column>>date In the drop down day then day

Having said that in direct query mode you will have to do it at the source. where the data is coming from

Answer (score 1):

We can just use day function. We could not use format function as it does not work for direct query mode.

```
DayNum = DAY(Data[Full Date])
```